# What is wrong with my libcrypto linking on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

I am trying to link my c++ program against the libcrypto library, using Cygwin and Windows.

I have this in my .cc file

```
#include <openssl/dh.h>
```

I have the header file dh.h in usr/include/openssl

And I have the required files (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) in /usr/lib/ however, when I build (using the python build tool node-waf),  I get errors such as `undefined reference to _DH_new`

I have tried various things in the cxxflags section of the build script, which now looks like this:

```
ppp.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-L/usr/lib", "-lssl","-llibeay32","-lssleay32"]
```

Comment: [It looks like a `libcrypto.a` is available](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=openssl-devel%2Fopenssl-devel-0.9.8r-2&grep=openssl) -- is that sufficient for your project?

Comment: It would be I believe, and I have that file. But I'm using the build system 'waf' and I'm not sure how to tell the linker to use libcrypto.a

Comment: Basically I tried using libcrypto.a, without any luck (I dont know why) and now I'm trying an alternative approach. But if you can help with statically linking libcrypto.a, I'm willing to return to that approach.

Comment: cygwin do .dll, not .so. You have something not built for cygwin.

Comment: aha. are you saying that I cannot use libcrypto.a or licrypto.so as neither are appropriate for Cygwin? I have been suspecting this, can you confirm?

Comment: more info needed. *when* do you see the undefined reference error? Any binary produced? What is the command it used to link?

Comment: When I run the build script I get the undefined reference error. I am running the command `node-waf configure build` If you look in the comments to the answer below you will see the relevant part of the build script. (python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Libcrypto.so is Linux's dynamically linked library.
According to [this](http://www.ski-epic.com/2007_notes_on_openssl/index.html) on Windows You need to use libeay32.a and ssleay32.a.
If that doesn't work You have to make your own library from OpenSSL source.

Comment: Do I need the .a files? Or do you think I should try and build openssl instead?

Comment: .a files are simply static libraries. It should be possible to link dlls dynamically.

Comment: `ppp.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-L/usr/lib", "-lssl","-llibeay32","-lssleay32"]`

Comment: Do I need to tell the compiler about each .dll?

Comment: Why did you say 'if that doesn't work': why wouldn't it? (It doesn't but I'm wondering why?)

Comment: I have marked this as correct since it has got me a lot closer than I was. However, I still cant build. I'm on day 3 now and getting desperate!

Comment: If i recall correctly dll should be in the same folder as executable or in system defined folder (if not found in program folder).

http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html - last section should help.

Comment: What it took in the end was `ppp.lib='crypto'` in the wscript.