# libcrypto equivalent missing on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, libcrypto

I have a C file that I need compiled on Windows7.  I have installed MinGW for gcc.  I also need OpenSSL, so followed the links from their site and downloaded the full developer package from Shining Light Productions (along with the 64-bit Redistro package from MS).

When I try to compile my file using this command:

```
gcc -D_WIN32 -O2 -shared -Wl,--kill-at -lcrypto -I%JAVA_HOME%\include -I%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32 -IC:\OpenSSL-Win64\include -LC:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib -lm -std=c99 osaccess.c -o libosaccess.dll
```

I get the error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I find particularly peculiar, is the unix-style forward slashes used in the error.  Also, the path is correct, but the case is not.  The valid path is `C:\MinGW\bin...`  I also cannot find any crypto library (either libcrypto.* or crypt*lib.*) anywhere, so I guess this is why it cannot find `-lcrypto`.  I would've thought that this would've come with the full install.  Has anyone else encountered this before, or know of why it may be happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my libcrypto linking on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566746/what-is-wrong-with-my-libcrypto-linking-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct library name for the Shining Light distribution is `libeay32` (found at `lib/libeay32.lib`). This library corresponds to `libcrypto`.